# Cyberpet timer assistance

Tags: c++, timer

What I'm trying to do is create a timer that will see my pets health slowly decline overtime (I want it lose one health every 5 seconds), And it get tired overtime (+ 1 tiredness over 10 seconds).
The timer is what I'm struggling with and getting it to correspond with health and tierdness I can't seem to get it to work and for some reason the code keeps repeating over and over again can you help?

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock the_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::complex;
using namespace std::chrono;
std::chrono::duration<long long>;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int icounter;
    int pettiredness = 0;
    
    string petname;
    int pethealth = 100;
    int feed = +5;
    the_clock::time_point start = the_clock::now();
    int curentseconds = 100;

    int option = 0;
    int petrest = -5;
    auto time_taken = 0;
    

    while (pethealth > 0)
    {
        cout << " your pets health is " << pethealth << endl;
        cout << "=========================" << endl;
        cout << "===         Pet Feeder          ===" << endl;
        cout << "1.  Feed pet" << endl;
        cout << "2.  Sleep pet" << endl;
        cout << "3.  Exit" << endl;

        switch (option) {
        
        case 1:
            pethealth = pethealth + feed;
            if (time_taken == 10)
                pethealth = pethealth - 5;
            cout << "your pet has been fed" << endl;

        case 2:
            pettiredness = petrest;

        case 3:
            pethealth;
            cout << pethealth << endl;

        
        }
    
        while ( pethealth == 75)
        {
            cout << "you pet is pekish" << endl;
        }

        if (pethealth == 50)
        {
            cout << "your pet is hungry" << endl;
        }

        if (pethealth == 0)
        {
            cout << "your pet has died" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "you need to feed your pet" << endl;
        }

        if (pettiredness == 50)
        {
            cout << "you pet is feeling tired" << endl;
        }

        if (pettiredness == 100)
        {
            cout << "your pet is asleep" << endl;
        }

    }

    the_clock::time_point end = the_clock::now();
    time_taken = duration_cast<seconds>(end - start).count();
    cout << "the pet was alive for " << time_taken << " seconds " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You display some menu for the user and then you switch on `option` here:

```
switch (option) {
```

But you never assigned something to `option` after initialization. I suppose you forgot to add a line:

```
std::cin >> option;
```

Though, consider that users can be slow and there is no simple way to interrupt the `std::cin` when the time is up.

Also this loop:

```
    while ( pethealth == 75)
    {
        cout << "you pet is pekish" << endl;
    }
```

will not ever end. If it is executed once, because `pethealth==75` then it will loop forever, because `pethealth` is not modified inside the loop. I think this is a typo and you wanted `if` instead.

Comment: ok it has stopped looping but the pet just dies instantly and i don't seem. to be able to issue command like feed and rest